# Error when trying to debug LeetCode answer on local environment

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am working on LeetCode problem [199. Binary Tree Right Side View](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-right-side-view/):

> Given the root of a binary tree, imagine yourself standing on the right side of it, return the values of the nodes you can see ordered from top to bottom.

I want to debug my code on my IDE (I use Visual Studio Code). It should be possible because I understand the theory behind it, but I don't understand well how this code works properly. Is it possible to debug it locally?

This is the code I am trying to debug:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def rightSideView(root):
        res = [ ]
        if not root :
            return res
        queue = [ root ]
        
        while queue :
            
            for n in range(len(queue)) :# 1
                
                first_val = queue.pop(0)
                print("first val",first_val)
                print("n",n)
                
                if n == 0 :
                    res.append(first_val.val)
                    
                if first_val.right :
                    queue.append(first_val.right)
                    
                if first_val.left :
                    queue.append(first_val.left)
        return res

    print(rightSideView([1,2,3,None,5,None,4]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LeetCode container will call your function with an argument that is a `ListNode` instance (or `None`), not with a list.

The input that LeetCode works with is **text**, and the notation used to describe the input is typically JSON-like. The LeetCode framework reads this text and first transforms it to a `ListNode` instance before calling your function.

So when you want to test your code outside of that platform, you'll need to do that preprocessing yourself. For instance, if your input is a Python list, then use a function like the following to first convert that list to a tree (`ListNode`):

```
def makeTree(lst):
    if not lst:
        return
    values = iter(lst)
    root = TreeNode(next(values))
    queue = [root]
    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0)
        if node:
            children = [
                None if value is None else TreeNode(value)
                for value in (next(values, None), next(values, None))
            ]
            queue.extend(children)
            node.left, node.right = children

    return root
```

Now you can run your test like this:

```
print(rightSideView(makeTree([1,2,3,None,5,None,4])))
```

Note that the code in your question has some indentation issues: the `rightSideView` function is not supposed to be a *method* of the `TreeNode` class. And the final `print` should not be part of that class either, so both should be unindented one step.

Comment: OK, I didn't think of dealing with 0. Script corrected.

Comment: correct now. Well done